# PHP Login Page isn't working correctly

Tags: php, html, sql

Recently I'm working on another project about Message Board.

When I finished my back-end pages, and doing some test, some problem occurs.

I try to investigating on login page(Ref.: [Example code in Pastebin for admin_login.php](http://pastebin.com/UZvQ5nWy)), I found that login script in php isn't working correctly even there has some certain data in my database:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['usr'])){
            require("connect.php");
            $username=$_POST['usr'];
            $password=$_POST['pwd'];
            $data=mysql_query("select * from admin where usr = '$username' and pwd = '$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($data)>=1){
                    header("location:admin_index.php");
            }else{
                    header("location:admin_login.php?msg=error");
            }
    }
?>
```

Could any suggestions to deal with that?

**UPDATED IN 10/28/15:**

Today I'm doing another investgation and also changed my code to this below:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
        require("connect-settings.php");

        // username and password sent from form1
        $username=$_POST['user'];
        $password=$_POST['pass'];

        // To protect MySQL injection
        $username=stripslashes($_POST['user']);
        $password=stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
        $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']); 

        $sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1){
            session_register("username");
            session_register("password");
            header("location:admin.php");
        } else {
            header("location:login.php?msg=loginfail");
            echo $count;
        }
    }
?>
```

and I found some issue for it.

It returns 0 rows.

Could somewhere needs to tweaking?

Comment: Wrap all your table and column names in backticks to prevent mysl reserved words error. Also note that `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed instead us `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. After `header` use `exit();` to prevent futher execution of any script. Your user input is also wide open to sql injection

Comment: @SuperDJ Thank you. I'll try this.

Comment: if you `echo` your `$sql` variable and run the query in mysql, does it return the correct values? If so, are you connected to the correct database?

Comment: Well, are you sure a corresponding user exists in the database? Why aren't you checking the values returned by `mysql_query()` and `mysql_num_rows()`? There are a few other problems with your code. (1) Stop using the `mysql_` functions; they have been deprecated and will disappear from PHP in the near future. Use the `mysqli_` functions instead. (2) Your database contains unencrypted passwords. This is a bad idea. Use PHP's [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to protect them. (3) You spelt "localtion" wrong.

Comment: @Digifaktur I checked my connection, and it connected to the correct database. But it still return 0 rows.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Thank you. I'll fix that ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your connect_settings.php the variable in which you are storing connection information ( `result from mysql_connect` ).
Also i see that you are not specifying the database during query, check that you are calling

`mysql_select_db("my_database")`

When calling the

`mysql_query($sql, $connection_variable)`

add the $connection_variable where you stored the connection information.

A note about your sql injection procedure:

```
// username and password sent from form1
$username=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username=stripslashes($_POST['user']);
$password=stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

you are using $username and $password for the query and you are overwriting them each time. Only `mysql_real_escape_string` result is stored in $username and $password.

so

```
// username and password sent from form1
$username=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username=stripslashes($_POST['user']);
$password=stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
```

are useless.
You should change it in:

```
// username and password sent from form1
$username=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username=stripslashes($username);
$password=stripslashes($password);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

But i doubt that adding the effect of stripslashes to mysql_real_escape_string will add any benefit. mysql_real_escape_string has some defect related to character encoding that makes it vulnerable, this offers only a basic protection. You should switch to mysqli_* set of functions or to the other alternative called PDO.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to change all the code with `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: it won't change your problem. Search the error first.